# Extracting the year from text in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have been trying to extract the year from my column entries that are in text format.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(55), startdttm)) as correct,
       EXTRACT(year from correct)
FROM table1
```

When running the code I've been getting the following error: SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "," which highlights the comma between the arguments of the inner convert. What is wrong with my conversion? Thanks

Comment: Probably you shouldn't specify the length here

Comment: Which database are you trying to do this on? Oracle for example can't reference an alias the way you're trying to here

Comment: `startdttm` of which type is it?

Comment: error message is postgresql

Comment: @NiVeR tried not to specify the length and got another error: Error [42703]: ERROR: column "datetime" does not exist. startdttm is text

Comment: @ZynonPutneyII I'm using PostgreSQL

Comment: You probably want something like EXTRACT(YEAR FROM to_date(startdttm, <your date pattern>)) where you'll have to check how your date is stored. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-formatting.html  Unfortunately, I don't have a PostgreSQL environment to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes no sense.  You seem quite confused.

In Postgres, `convert()` is used to convert between different character encodings (see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#CONVERSION-NAMES)).  That is, it is almost never used.

Second, Postgres does not have a `datetime` data type.  It uses `timestamp`, available in flavors with and without a timezone.

You could phrase the logic using `CAST()`:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(startdttm as varchar(255)) as timestamp) as correct,  -- you can leave off the (255)
```

More commonly in Postgres, this is expressed using `::`:

```
SELECT startdttm::varchar(255)::timestamp as correct  -- you can leave off the (255)
```

And, further, you cannot use a table alias in the `SELECT` where it is defined.  So, you would seem to want:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM startdttm::varchar::timestamp) as yyyy
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to SQL. Your comment solved most of the problems that I was having! =)